# Code double printing a line

Tags: java

```
    char grade;
    for(int x=1; x<6; x++){
        System.out.print("Please enter your course grade here: ");
        grade = (char) System.in.read();
    }
    System.out.println("Thank you! Keep up the good work!");
}
```

So that is my code, seems right but this is the output.

```
Please enter your course grade here: A
Please enter your course grade here: Please enter your course grade here: A
Please enter your course grade here: Please enter your course grade here: A
Thank you! Keep up the good work!
```

By the way I inputed the A's.
So do any of you have an idea why this would be happening?

Comment: use a scanner to get the input.... it will block the sequence until the user gives the input...

Comment: This is for school and my teacher only wants me to use read and for loops.

Comment: The newline characters are being processed at the same time as your `'A'` characters.  So, 3 of your grades are `'A'` and the other 2 grades are `'\n'`.

Comment: Then your teacher doesn't know how to get data back from a user in Java that well if you must use `System.in.read();`

Comment: So there is no way to fix it?

Comment: If we have to use `System.in.read()`, then yes, I guess you could, but it is really really bad way to do it. You'll have to check for input and skip an input each time. You really should be using a scanner. It's like your teacher told you that you need to fix his issues w/the soup, but you can only use a fork to eat it!

Comment: So how could I do that?

Comment: `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);` and then do `scanner.nextLine()` to get the string of the next line... or simply `String line = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();`

Comment: With a system.in.read by the way RoiEX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
char grade;
for(int x=1; x<6; x++){
    System.out.print("Please enter your course grade here: ");
    grade = (char) System.in.read();
    while (grade == '\n')
        grade = (char) System.in.read();
}
System.out.println("Thank you! Keep up the good work!");
}
```

But it's untested. In theory it should ignore any newlines.

Comment: Thank you so much!